# "No default Typeable for parametrized type" using Shapeless 2.1.0-RC2

Tags: scala, shapeless

I was trying to use Shapeless Typeable to make access to Java libraries a bit more type-safe, but ran into a roadblock. I'm not sure if I'm misusing the library, have to manually provide a type-class instance, or if something else is going wrong.

A simplified demonstration of my issue is demonstrated by this code..

```
import shapeless._
import syntax.typeable._

def gaugeOpt(name: String): Option[Gauge[Double]] = {
  return registry.getGauges.get(name).cast[Gauge[Double]]
}
```

..results in this error using Shapeless-2.1.0-RC2 and Scala 2.11.5:

```
No default Typeable for parametrized type com.codahale.metrics.Gauge[Double]
```

The library shown is not really important; just interested in the general pattern of making Java libraries more type-safe when I use them from my Scala code.

**Solution:**

Using the advice from the accepted answer I wrote the following type class instance:

```
implicit def gaugeTypeable[T](implicit castT: Typeable[T]): Typeable[Gauge[T]] =
  new Typeable[Gauge[T]] {
    def cast(t: Any): Option[Gauge[T]] = {
      if(t == null) None
      else if(t.isInstanceOf[Gauge[_]]) {
        castT.cast(t.asInstanceOf[Gauge[_]].getValue) match {
          case None => None
          case _ => Some(t.asInstanceOf[Gauge[T]])
        }
      } else None
    }
  }
```

The only caveat being that I had to access the gauge value accessor to recover the erased type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a default `Typeable` instance for unparameterized types, because you can safely (ish) cast them by just checking their runtime class. But since generics are erased at runtime, this would be unsafe for parameterized types; `t.getClass()` might return `Gauge.class`, but that's no guarantee that `t` is a `Gauge[Double]` and not, say, a `Gauge[Int]`.

You need to manually provide a typeclass instance:

```
implicit def gaugeTypeable[A](implicit innerTypeable: Typeable[A]) =
  new Typeable[Gauge[A]] {
    def cast(t: Any): Option[Gauge[A]] = ...
      //confirm whether t is really a Gauge[A]
      //probably making use of innerTypeable to check the
      //"inner" value
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured that might be the issue, but I figured I would check first. I will look at the type class implementation for List for guidance.