# How to match a Case Class containing a Parameter with Generic Type

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, akka, shapeless

I have an interesting Problem matching a Case Class in Scala....

I am using Akka and I have functionality that I will use in every Actor in my System, so created a Base Class for my Actor and I try to Match that Command there....

My Command looks like the following...

```
sealed trait ReportCommand extends ProcessCommand
final case class onReport(key: Key, replyTo: ActorRef[ResponseBase[State]]) extend ReportCommand
```

while I constructed Base Class so that it might be used from different Actors, `onReport` is delivered to Base Actor as generic parameter to be used in pattern match with a case class ...

```
abstract class BaseActor[E: ClassTag, R <: ReportBase[STATE], COMMAND](signal: TypeCase[R]) {
    private val report = signal        

    def base[B <: E: ClassTag](cmd: E, state: STATE)(f: B => ReplyEffect[COMMAND, STATE]): ReplyEffect[COMMAND, STATE] = 
      cmd match {
        case report(report) => 
           Effect.reply(report.replytTo)(new ResponseBase[STATE]{
             override def state: STATE = state
           }) 
      }
}
```

First if you think this construct will not work, it works, I have another Command (which I didn't place here) which does not have a generic parameter in the Command Class and above snippet is able to match that Snippet.

Now when I first try this code, Shapeless is complained about there is no mapping to ActorRef for Typeable of TypeCase, so after researching the internet I found I have to do the following....

```
implicit def mapActorRef[T: ClassTag]: Typeable[ActorRef[T]] =
   new Typeable[ActorRef[T]] {
      private val typT = Typeable[T]

      override def cast(t: Any) : Option[ActorRef[T]] = {
         if(t==null) None
         else if(t.isInstanceOf[ActorRef[_]]) {
           val o= t.asInstanceOf[ActorRef[_]]
           for {
             _ <- typT.cast(myClassOf)
           } yield o.asInstanceOf[ActorRef[T]]
         } else None
      }
   }

def myClassOf[T: ClassTag] = implicitly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass

implicit def responseBaseIsTypeable[S: Typeable] : Typeable[ResponseBase[S]] =
   new Typeable[ResponseBase[S]] {
      private val typS = Typeable[S]
         
      override def cast(t: Any) : Option[ResponseState[S]] = {
         if(t==null) None
         else if(t.isIntanceOf[ResponseBase[_]]) {
            val o = t.asInstanceOf[ResponseBase[_]]
            for {
              _ <- typS.cast(o.state)
            } yield o.asInstanceOf[ResponseBase[S]]
         } else None
      }
   }
```

Now after this changes I don't receive any Exceptions from Shapeless but `case report(report)` is not matching, I have no idea how we get a reasoning from Scala why it decide it does not match. During my debugging session I observed the following.

I am using the Akka's Ask Pattern to communicate with this actor...

```
val future : Future[BaseActor.ResponseBase[Actor.State]] = actorRef.ask[BaseActor.ResponseBase[Actor.State]](ref =>
   Actor.onReport(key, ref)
)
```

now if I observe the cmd object that BaseActor receives, I see that 'ask' Pattern of the Akka change ActorRef in the `onReport` Command class to an ActorRefAdapter, of course ActorRefAdapter is a subclass of an ActorRef but I am not sure what I defined in the implicit for mapping ActorRef to TypeCase can deal with that stuff but I can't figure a way to change implicit to be aware of the Subtypes....

Unfortunately ActorRefAdapter is private to package `package akka.actor.typed.internal.adapter` so I can't define an extra mapping for ActorRefAdapter.

So can anybody see why Scala is not matching over my Shapeless <-> TypeCase configuration and give me some tips...

Thx for answers...

Comment: Have you tried `private val Report = signal`?  Scala has some hardcoded heuristics around letter-case in a pattern match.

Comment: My other command that I mention (which is getting matched) is also written with small letters but I will try

Comment: @posthumecaver Some parts of your code are not valid Scala, e.g. `final case class(key: Key, replyTo: ActorRef[ResponseBase[State]])`. Please prepare [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or provide your `build.sbt`+imports making your code self-contained.

Comment: Yes, you are right copy/paste sry, I fixed that...I developed this project with IntelliJ Scala Plugin with gradle scala plugin, so I don't have the sbt files, plus this is a really specific project requiring a Cassandra in Docker container, so it is little bit difficult to transfer as reproduceable case but I will try write a small project which just replicates this problem

Comment: @posthumecaver Any build file is ok (sbt/gradle/maven/whatever). Please do. Otherwise it's hard to reproduce in order to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi, it was a little fight but a reproducible case is there https://github.com/mehmetsalgar/scala_pattern_matching under the main/test/scala you will find a FirstSpec test, if you debug that and set a BreakPoint at BaseActor case statement you will see that onReport Command ist not  matched. I tried to make as easy as possible a reproducible so Akka Actor probably does not make too much sense but you can see where the problem lies...

Answer (score 0):

Your instance `Typeable[ActorRef[T]]` is incorrect.

Why did you decide to substitute a `ClassTag` in `typT.cast(myClassOf)`? This can't be meaningful.

I guess you used something like ["No default Typeable for parametrized type" using Shapeless 2.1.0-RC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28300776)

If your gole is to make `case report(replyTo)` matching then you can define

```
implicit def mapActorRef[T: Typeable]: Typeable[ActorRef[T]] =
  new Typeable[ActorRef[T]] {
    private val typT = Typeable[T]

    override def cast(t: Any): Option[ActorRef[T]] = {
      if (t == null) None
      else util.Try(t.asInstanceOf[ActorRef[T]]).toOption
    }

    override def describe: String = s"ActorRef[${typT.describe}]"
  }
```

The problem is that this instance is also bad. Now `case report(replyTo)` is matching too much.

```
val actorTestKit = ActorTestKit()
val replyToRef = actorTestKit.spawn(ReplyToActor(), "replyTo")

import BaseActor._ // importing implicits
import shapeless.syntax.typeable._
val future: Future[BaseActor.ResponseBase[Actor.State]] = replyToRef.cast[ActorRef[Int]].get.ask[BaseActor.ResponseBase[Actor.State]](ref =>
  1
)(5.seconds, system.scheduler)

Await.result(future, 10.seconds) // ClassCastException
```

A legal instance of the type class `Typeable` can be defined not for every type.

> Providing instances for (concrete instantiations of) polymorphic types (where well defined) is pretty much the whole point of `Typeable`, both here and in Haskell.
>
> The key phrase in the above is "where well defined". It's well defined in the case of non-empty container-like things. It's clearly not well defined for function values.

https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/issues/69

`ResponseBase` is a *non-empty container-like thing*. But `ActorRef` is like a function `T => Unit`, so there shouldn't be a `Typeable` for it

```
trait ActorRef[-T] extends ... {
  def tell(msg: T): Unit

  ...
}
```

You should reconsider your approach.